# Traefik - 404 when "offset=1" is first query parameter

Tags: django-rest-framework, traefik

I have a django rest framework application which sits behind Traefik. Everything is working perfectly EXCEPT for a single query parameter, which is `offset`. Specifically, `offset=1*`. When this query parameter is present, Traefik returns a 404.

As an example, a `GET` request to `myapi?something=thing` works, and returns 200. A `GET` request to `myapi?offset=200` works, and returns a 200. A `GET` request to `myapi?offset=100` does not work, and returns a 404.

In other words, it seems like `offset=1` has special meaning to Traefik, but I could not find any information on this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this had nothing at all to do with Traefik, and my initial testing was flawed anyway. I was using the pagination links provided by DRF, which were linking to http instead of https. Since Traefik was not configured to proxy HTTP, I was getting the 404.